# Echo array just give the output array instead of value

Tags: php

This loop just gives me the output `Array` instead of the value that shows when I use the `print_r` function.

`print_r` gives me this:

```
Array
(
  [0] => 1
  [1] => 2
  [2] => 3
  [3] => 1
)
```

but the echo just array

```
for($i=0; $i<($n*$n); $i++){

        for($j=0; $j<($n*$n); $j++){
        $number = "column" . $i . $j;
        $plan = $field[$i][$j] = $_POST[$number];
        $myvariable[] = $field[$i][$j];

        }
        echo $myvariable;
    }
```

but if I remove the `[]` from `$myvariable` it prints out the values. the problem is that I need to use the array with an unique array

```
$unique = array_unique($myvariable);
    if (count($unique) != count($myvariable)) {
 echo ="no uniques";

}
```

Any tips?

Comment: Actually am confused of what you exactly want to achieve here

Comment: Am still not understanding but I guess what you want is to loop through unique `array` so make your `array` unique first and than loop through

Comment: Is there a reason you want/need to echo in your loop?

Comment: @Mr.Alien shankar just gave me an little help. I was trying to remove the values that vere not unique

Comment: @Dymond Yea, he just answered what I told :) and btw not the downvoter here, I hardly downvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean this ?

```
$unique = array_unique($myvariable);
foreach($unique as $value)
{
echo $value;
}
```

or make use of a typical **`for`**

```
$unique = array_unique($myvariable);
for($i=0;$i<count($unique);$i++)
{
echo $unique[$i];
}
```

Comment: this is just what i was trying to do. thank you very much my friend